# Make one div inside two div and auto scale image subdiv

Tags: html, css

```html
<div id="main">
    <div id="pictureDiv">
        <img src="img.png">
    </div>
    <div id="pictureDiv">
        <p>safsdghfghjghjkhkhjkhjkklhjkjh</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

How to make that image fit to div and text fit to div and make all responsive.THANK YOU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the image to be:

```
img {
 max-width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}
```

To make your div to resize with the parent, set the width to be relative to the parents using percentage:

```
 div {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
 }
```